# Unknown column in query

Tags: sql-server

I have a small idea for that but i don't know how to interpret it in SQL Server (MSDN).

```
IF ('DateReception' is not NULL) AND ('DateMovement' is NULL) 
        SET @Requete = DATEDIFF (dd, @EndDatereq, 'DateReception')
        SET @Requete = 'SELECT A.[AutomatonStatus]
            FROM dbo.Automatons A
            WHERE ((A.AutomatonStatus = "SNI") OR (A.AutomatonStatus = "PAI") OR (A.AutomatonStatus = "INP") OR (A.AutomatonStatus = "INT"))'
```

After that I get  an error message :

> Msg 207, Niveau 16, État 1, Ligne 3
>   Nom de colonne non valide : 'SNI'.

Comment: "Message 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 3 Invalid column name 'SNI'.  En anglais, svp.

Answer (score 1):

The SQL you're showing doesn't make much sense out of context.

For some reason the server is interpreting the constant `SNI` as a column name.

Comment: don't comment if you don't have the answer plz. It's a waste of time

Answer (score 0):

Enclose your string constants into double single quotes, not double quotes:

```
IF ('DateReception' is not NULL) AND ('DateMovement' is NULL) 
        SET @Requete = DATEDIFF (dd, @EndDatereq, 'DateReception')
        SET @Requete = 'SELECT A.[AutomatonStatus]
            FROM dbo.Automatons A
            WHERE ((A.AutomatonStatus = ''SNI'') OR (A.AutomatonStatus = ''PAI'') OR (A.AutomatonStatus = ''INP'') OR (A.AutomatonStatus = ''INT''))'
```

Double quotes mark an identifier (column name etc), not string.

Comment: One more question, i want to convert a NVARCHAR to DATE and i also want to make DATEDIFF.